# Swift pull to reload duplicates objects in table instead of updating

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am importing data from parse and trying to add a "pull to refresh" function so if someone adds an object it will add to the tableview, however right now it duplicates whats already in the tableview. Obviously if nothing has been added and i refresh nothing should change.

Much help would be aprecciated

Here is my code below

```
 var refresher: UIRefreshControl!

func Refresh() {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Events")

    query.orderByAscending("Date")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            // query successful - display number of rows found
            print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) Events")
            if let objects = objects {
                for object in objects {

                    self.postedEvents.append(object.objectForKey("Name") as! String)      
                    self.postedImages.append(object.objectForKey("Image") as! PFFile)
                    self.postedObjects.append(object)

                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    self.refresher.endRefreshing()
                }
                print(self.postedObjects.count)
                print(self.postedEvents)
            }

        } else {

            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog("Error: %@ %@", error!, error!.userInfo)
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {


    refresher = UIRefreshControl()
    refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to Refresh")
    refresher.addTarget(self, action: "Refresh", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

    self.tableView.addSubview(refresher)

    Refresh()

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try at first line of `Refresh()`:

```
self.postedEvents.removeAll()
self.postedImages.removeAll()
self.postedObjects.removeAll()
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Could you please explain to me why i need to do this?

Comment: Every time `Refresh` is called, you `append(object)`. So it will contain more and more items. You just need to clear them before new objects come in. BTW, maybe better to put these codes after the line of `if error == nil`

Comment: it doesn't makes sense append when I'm using refresh but this is how it works. Your answer helped me too, thank

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `createdAt` time of most recent original object you have, and in your refresh function say `query.whereKey("createdAt", greaterThanOrEqualTo: self.pastRecentTime)` and this will only pull the most recent objects.

Comment: i have an error, with the self.pastRecentTime. do i need to declare this as a variable anywhere? also where abouts do i put that line of code?

Comment: Yes this is something you have to create, and it would just be a class variable that get's updated every time you run a new query.